# PHP md5 in conditional

Tags: php, md5

I have a simple script that i am trying to do a simple md5 user/password om. the problem i am having is that regardless of what i put in the user/pass fields it matches the conditionals and allows the include to load

```
<?php
if(md5($_POST['user']) === 'md5user' && md5($_POST['pass']) === 'md5pass'):    
    include("secure.php");   
else: ?>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width: 20%;">
            <div class="row-fluid well" style="background: #333; margin-top: 25%;">
                <p class="lead">Inventory Update Login</p>
                <form class="form" method="POST" action="secure.php">
                <label>User Name</label><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="user"></input><br/>
                <label>Password</label><input class="input-block-level" type="password" name="pass"></input><br/>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
                </form>
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                      <h4>Warning!</h4>
                      Best check yo self, you're not supposed to be here by accident. If you are here to do something naughty, keep in mind we are a company owned by people with guns!
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

secure.php:

```
<?php
    $secretkey = "12345";
    print_r($_POST);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dev.zinkcalls.com/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <style>
            body {color: #fff;}
            .well, .brand, .navbar-inner, .popover, .btn, .tooltip, input, select, textarea, pre, .progress, .modal, .add-on, .alert, .table-bordered, .nav>.active>a, .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .tooltip-inner, .badge, .label, .img-polaroid {
                background-image: none !important;
                border-collapse: collapse !important;
                box-shadow: none !important;
                    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
                   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
                border: none;
                text-shadow: none !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width: 20%;">
            <div class="row-fluid well" style="background: #333; margin-top: 25%;">
                <?php if((!isset($_POST['key']) or ($_POST['key'] != $secretkey)) and !isset($_POST['update'])): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        <h4>Whoaa!</h4>You need the secret key bro.
                    </div>
                    <form class="form" method="POST" action="secure.php">
                        <label>Secret Key</label><input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="key" /><br/>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter Secret Key" />   
                    </form>
                <?php elseif(($_POST['key'] = $secretkey) and !isset($_POST['update'])): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        <h4>Careful!</h4>
                        You may destroy everything in one click of the button. Proceed?
                    </div>
                    <form class="form" method="POST" action="secure.php">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="update" value="Yes" />
                        <input class="btn" type="reset" name="abort" value="No" />
                    </form>
                <?php else:?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <?php include("inventory_query.php"); ?>
                        <h4>Done!</h4>
                        Now get the hell outta here.
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <hr />
                <form class="form" method="POST" action="inventory.php">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout" />   
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hum where is the endif???

Comment: why are you usin `:` at the end of `if` and `else` ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't also include secure.php somewhere else? Is the HTML part displayed on your page? (What does secure.php does? I mean, how do you know it's included?)

Comment: it is not inclded anywhere else. the html is displayed on the page. regardless of what is submitted, the file is included and the above form disappears.

Comment: Your code seems fine, what does your address-bar say, `http://localhost/secure.php`?

Comment: address bar just shows https://dev.domain.com/secure.php

Comment: Can you edit your post with the include?

Comment: Your form action submits to secure.php : `<form class="form" method="POST" action="secure.php">` . Of course secure.php will be called in that case. Change your "action" value to your current page.

Comment: Sidenote: MD5 dates back to the early 90's and is no longer considered safe to use. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is submitted to `secure.php` and since that file doesn't contain this check (I assume) everything in it is just executed/displayed. Remove the `action="secure.php"` from the `form`-tag to POST to self.

PS. learn about [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) if you want a more persistent login.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, firstly, `md5` should not be used with passwords for security reasons. [Please read](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) into the topic, as I will not go into much detail.

That being said, here is the issue you are experiencing.

[`md5`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) is going to return an md5 hash of the supplied string. For example:

```
echo md5('md5pass'); // 65ed8a5eec59a1a6f75ec845294aead8
```

That **will not** change. It is a **new** string and can not be compared to it's raw counterpart, in this case 'md5pass'. What you can do, would be to compare the hash of the user supplied value to an expected value.

In this case, `md5($_POST['pass']) === md5('md5pass')`, would only evaluate if `$_POST['pass']` is 'md5pass'.

Again, please look into **hashing your passwords**.

### Edit:

@Peter van der Wal is correct as well. You are never going to execute the check you want until you correct the form action.